# Javascript in partial won't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run some Javascript on my page from a partial - I can't use the standard .js javascript files built in rails because I have to pass variables to them.  Because of this, I am trying to use erb with Javascript variables inside (ex <%= @person.name %>).

For some reason, when I add a simple alert, the browser doesn't run the javascript.  Am I doing anything wrong, or does this have something to do with Rails4?  Here's what I am doing:

**In my partial (myjs.js.erb)**

```
<script language="javascript" type="javascript/text">
  alert('Javascript is working!');
</script>
```

**In my view (which is haml)**

```
= render 'myjs.js'
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is the output of the page. plz paste the html source code of the page from the browser.

Comment: It seems strange to me to use a <script> inside a .js file

Comment: @jelle - I took the <script> tag out and just kept the js text.  It rendered as standard text on the page.

Comment: Here's what renders on the page - inside of the <main> tag:  <script type="javascript/text" language="javascript">
        alert('my text');
      </script>

Comment: what happens when you change the extension from .js.erb to .html.erb?

Comment: The same thing happens - I can see the rendered script in the html source, but it's not executed by the browser.  I know the browser will run javascript because if I put javascript directly into a view, it will execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem is - hopefully this helps someone else.  I was entering 'javascript/text' instead of 'text/javascript' inside of the script block.  Here is the same code from my original question changed to execute javascript inside of a partial:

**In my partial (myjs.js.erb)**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Javascript is working!');
</script>
```

**In my view (which is haml)**

```
= render 'myjs.js'
```

**Followup thoughts**

I am using Google Chrome, so I am not sure if it's the only browser sensitive to this.  If you come across the problem of executing javascript code in a partial, try to change the order of the type value!